# Firefox browser closes without opening the specified URL

Tags: selenium

I am new to Selenium as can be seen by me specifying the absolute path while identifying elements. I have written a simple code for opening gmail login page which is 
`

```
package SeleniumScripts;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class LogintoGmail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");`enter code here`
    //  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer_x64_3.8.0\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    //  WebDriver driver=new InternetExplorerDriver();  
        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/form/div[2]/div/div/div/ul[1]/li[1]/div/div[2]/p[2]")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/form/content/section/div/content/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/input")).sendKeys("12!harley");
        String apptitle=driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(apptitle);

    }

}
```

`
While running the code Firefox opens & then without opening the URL closes.I am getting the below error during execution:

> 

```
1541589284453   Marionette  DEBUG   Remote service is active
1541589284765   Marionette  DEBUG   Accepted connection 0 from 127.0.0.1:51510
1541589284777   Marionette  TRACE   0 -> [0,1,"newSession",{"acceptInsecureCerts":true,"browserName":"firefox","capabilities":{"desiredCapabilities":{"acceptInsecureCerts":true,"browserName":"firefox"}}}]
1541589284778   Marionette  TRACE   0 <- [1,1,{"error":"unknown command","message":"newSession","stacktrace":"WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:178: ... et@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:245:8\n_onJSONObjectReady/<@chrome://marionette/content/transport.js:490:9\n"},null]
Nov 07, 2018 4:44:45 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorCodes toStatus
INFO: HTTP Status: '404' -> incorrect JSON status mapping for 'unknown error' (500 expected)
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: newSession
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:03.216Z'
System info: host: 'USER-PC', ip: '192.168.43.64', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '9.0.4'
Driver info: driver.version: FirefoxDriver
remote stacktrace: WebDriverError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:178:5
UnknownCommandError@chrome://marionette/content/error.js:472:5
despatch@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:290:13
execute@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:271:11
onPacket/<@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:246:15
onPacket@chrome://marionette/content/server.js:245:8
_onJSONObjectReady/<@chrome://marionette/content/transport.js:490:9

    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$new$0(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:57)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.W3CHandshakeResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(W3CHandshakeResponse.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:207)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:130)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:125)
    at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:103)
    at SeleniumScripts.LogintoGmail.main(LogintoGmail.java:12)
```

Please note this was running fine one week back but now i am getting error.

Comment: _GeckoDriver_ and _Firefox_ versions?

Comment: Check this,are you using These Versions?https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases if yes, it will work. What is the Firefox Version?

Comment: Geckodriver version is "geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64",selenium webdriver version is "selenium-server-3.9.1", "selenium-java-3.12.0", Firefox version is 63.0, Java Version is 9.0.4. Can you please guide me regarding the version that i should use to get rid of these niggling issues. Also shall i switch off the auto-update feature of browsers when testing with Selenium

Answer (score 0):

```
    package SeleniumScripts;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class LogintoGmail {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\geckodriver-v0.19.1-win64\\geckodriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


        driver.get("http://www.gmail.com/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("X/PATH")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("X/PATH")).sendKeys("12!harley");
        String apptitle = driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println(apptitle);
```

Try copying what i've done, the code although extremely messy was correct just you didn't have spaces when you were declaring your firefox driver, there were two instances where you didn't have proper spacing and it does make a difference.

When the code is wrong, a lot of the time the driver will force the browser open but will leave the URL empty or a null value and not continue the test.

If i was you, i would start with just opening the page and build on top of the script.

Comment: Unfortunately i got the same result when i pasted your code & executed the same. Also can you please tell me why spacing matters so much in selenium. Can you please provide me any link where i can get these kind of guidelines regarding spacing. Also when you said that "i would start with just opening the page and build on top of the script" you mean i should write a separate class for getting title or performing any other action right. Can you please elaborate on the same..